# Need to calculate the Value of a pixel

Tags: c#

I have a RGBA values,
R - 255,
G - 103,
B - 103,
Alpha - 103.

Need combination of the (RGB) color value. Example - 26532.(combination of colour value/Pixel value)

Description - Image is made of pixels, each pixel has combination of colors(like - RGB).
Need to calculate the mean of the image and we need to have the unique value of the pixel.
Each pixel has 4 colour values but need the pixel value( combination of colour values)

Comment: How would *you* calculate that "value of a pixel"? Do you know how to get the ARGB value?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BitConverter` to convert the RGBA bytes to a single `int` value:

```
        byte[] components = new byte[4];
        components[0] = 103;        // blue
        components[1] = 103;        // green
        components[2] = 255;        // red
        components[3] = 103;        // alpha

        int pixelValue = BitConverter.ToInt32(components, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a loop through every pixel, and calculate the pixel value on the fly if you know the pixel color values.

Relevant questions:

> [How can I iterate through each pixel in a .gif image in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230188/how-can-i-iterate-through-each-pixel-in-a-gif-image-in-c)
>
> [How to calculate the average rgb color values of a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068373/how-to-calculate-the-average-rgb-color-values-of-a-bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = Color.FromArgb(103, 103, 255, 103).ToArgb()
```

Comment: i got the result using this code. 

 int r = objcolor.R;
 int g = objcolor.G;
 int b = objcolor.B;

int rgb = ((r & 0x0ff) << 16) | ((g & 0x0ff) << 8) | ((b & 0x0ff))