# Invert the colors of Captured finger print

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi, fingerprint

I am new to graphic programming. I have a code as below to capture the finger print from the scanner:

```
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CreateDIBitmap(IntPtr hdc, [In] ref BITMAPINFOHEADER lpbmih,
                                        uint fdwInit, byte[] lpbInit, byte[] lpbmi,
                                        uint fuUsage);


    /* constants for CreateDIBitmap */
    const int CBM_INIT = 0x04;   /* initialize bitmap */

    /* DIB color table identifiers */
    const int DIB_RGB_COLORS = 0; /* color table in RGBs */
    const int DIB_PAL_COLORS = 1; /* color table in palette indices */

    const int BI_RGB = 0;

    private Bitmap CreateBitmap(IntPtr hDC, Size bmpSize, byte[] data)
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream mem = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        System.IO.BinaryWriter bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(mem);
        //BITMAPINFO bmpInfo = new BITMAPINFO();
        BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader = new BITMAPINFOHEADER();
        bmiHeader.biSize = 40;
        bmiHeader.biWidth = bmpSize.Width;
        bmiHeader.biHeight = bmpSize.Height;
        bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
        bmiHeader.biBitCount = 8;
        bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
        bw.Write(bmiHeader.biSize);
        bw.Write(bmiHeader.biWidth);
        bw.Write(bmiHeader.biHeight);
        bw.Write(bmiHeader.biPlanes);
        bw.Write(bmiHeader.biBitCount);
        bw.Write(bmiHeader.biCompression);
        bw.Write(bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
        bw.Write(bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter);
        bw.Write(bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter);
        bw.Write(bmiHeader.biClrUsed);
        bw.Write(bmiHeader.biClrImportant);

        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            bw.Write((byte)i);
            bw.Write((byte)i);
            bw.Write((byte)i);
            bw.Write((byte)0);
        }

        IntPtr hBitmap;
        if (data != null)
        {
            hBitmap = CreateDIBitmap(hDC, ref bmiHeader, CBM_INIT, data, mem.ToArray(), DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        }
        else
        {
            hBitmap = CreateDIBitmap(hDC, ref bmiHeader, 0, null, mem.ToArray(), DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        }
        return Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
    }
```

Which generates an image with `Black` background and `White` ridges but I want to invert those color and I want `White` background with `Black` ridges.

Is it possible ?

Comment: where is data coming from? can you invert the values in data?

Comment: Yes it is possible. It depends how you want to do it. You can use libraries, you can loop through pixels and change its color.

Comment: @Reniuz Which one is efficient ? And can you give an example of how can it be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example which is (I thing) the easiest but it is slow. It's just to give you an idea how it can be done. Note `RGB(255,255,255)` is white and `RGB(0,0,0)` is black color. The idea is simple if you have pixel black so from 255 subtracting each color you will get white. And vice versa 255 - 0 = 255.

```
public Bitmap InvertBitmapColor(Bitmap img)
{
  Bitmap result = new Bitmap(img);
  Color currentColor, newColor;
  for(int x=0; x < img.Width; x++)
    for(int y=0; y < img.Height; y++)
    {
       currentColor = img.GetPixel(x, y);
       newColor = Color.FromArgb(255 - currentColor.R, 255 - currentColor.G, 255 - currentColor.B);
       result.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
    }
   return result;
}
```

If you need fast image processing use [LockBits](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx). You can find example of both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1230195/754438)